# iOS UIWebView setUserInteractionEnabled to NO does not work for iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios6, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView as a cell in a UITableView. I know this is not recommended, but the WebView is not scrolling, so the recommendation does not matter. I use the web view to style and theme the cell.

The problem I have is that in iOS 6, when I set userInteractionEnabled to NO, the UIWebView does not pass touch events up the responder chain. The table view never calls didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I should note this works fine in iOS 5.

My question is, has Apple changed how UIWebView handles userInteractionEnabled?

Any commentary would help.

This is where I make the call. It is being called on the correct cell instance (I only have 1 WebView cell in the table)

```
webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Do you add the webView to cell or cell.contentView?

Comment: I'm using a custom class.    @interface WebViewTableCell : UIWebView <UIWebViewDelegate>

Comment: When you build your cells in tableView datasource method, where do you append it as subview?

Comment: There is no need in subclassing..

Comment: I have other needs for subclassing

Answer (score 2):

Works fine in iOS 6

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height)];
    NSString *html = @"<div></div>";
    [wv loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    wv.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:wv];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: it looks like the only difference is that you add it to the contentview. I wonder if because my cell has no superview the touch event gets tossed. I'll see if implementing something similar to this solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use custom size of cell, you'll need to resize the webview in **tableView willDisplayCell** method.

Answer (score 0):

My problem had nothing to do with the userInteractionEnabled.

It was because I also override the shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath: method

```
- (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

and it seems that in iOs 6 this disables touch events to the cell at that indexPath. good to know.